# percent_rank special case to not include the value being evaluated in the range of group to be evaluated

Tags: excel, percentile

Consider these values:

```
company_ID    3yr_value
1            10
2            20
3            30
4            40
5            50
```

I have this statement on my query and my goal is to compute for the percent rank of value 50 in the group

```
round(((percent_rank() over (partition by bb.company_id order by bb.3yr_value)) * 100))
```

in excel, this is equivalent to

```
=percentrank(b1:b5,b5)
```

BUT, what I need is an equivalent to this 1:`=percentrank(b1:b4,b5)` -- notice that I don't include A5 in the range that needs to be evaluated. I'm out of options, and already consulted Mr. Google but it seems I still cant find the solution. I always end up including B5 in my query.

I'm using postgres sql